# Is there an alternative to CoreBluetooth for OSX

Tags: c++, objective-c, osx-mountain-lion, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Just checking to see if anyone has seen an alternative to using CoreBluetooth for bluetooth classic and bluetooth LE connections

Comment: Why can't you use CoreBluetooth?

Answer (score 3):

`CoreBluetooth.framework` only works for Bluetooth Low-Energy.
`ExternalAccessory.framework` (iOS), and its pendants in Mac OSX which is `IOBluetooth` ( I think that's the one) are for classic Bluetooth.
Since they are two different way of thinking and working, you can't use one to communicate with the other king of Bluetooth. You have to understand Bluetooth Low-Energy as a fork from classical Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

You also have [BTstack](http://code.google.com/p/btstack/). But that's only available to jailbroken devices.